# php generated strings not passed correctly to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

Summary
I have a simple Javascript function

```
<script>
  function PopUP($str) {alert($str);}
</script>
```

I am trying to pass a long JSON string to PopUP()
the string is

```
{"Date":"2021-09-13 22:25:42","From":"simard57@hotmail.com","Sect":"Other","Villa#":"my villa","VillaName":"Resort","Owner":"Simard","OwnerSite":"https:\/\/donsimard.wix.com\/DomRepAI","BRs":"1 BR","StreetMBR":"0","StreetBR":"0","UpperMBR":"0","UpperBR":"0","LowerMBR":"0","LowerBR":"0","Comments":"testing"}
```

the generated HREF is

```
<a HREF="javascript:PopUP('{"Date":"2021-09-13 22:25:42","From":"simard57@hotmail.com","Sect":"Other","Villa#":"my villa","VillaName":"Resort","Owner":"Simard","OwnerSite":"https:\/\/donsimard.wix.com\/DomRepAI","BRs":"1 BR","StreetMBR":"0","StreetBR":"0","UpperMBR":"0","UpperBR":"0","LowerMBR":"0","LowerBR":"0","Comments":"testing"}')">JSON</a>
```

the link seems to be truncated and not being passed to the Javascript function. am I missing something trivial?

---original post---

I have a form that is being processed by php file in the action. the code snippet below. It collects the form content passed by a GET and appends a JSON record to the end of the log file

```
$pathToJSONFile ="LHVC_Logs/LHVCResortMapLog.json";
$jsonToLog = array(
   "Date" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 
);
foreach ($_GET as $field => $entry) {
   $jsonToLog[$field] = $entry;
}
$json = json_encode($jsonToLog);
$json .= PHP_EOL;
$bytes = file_put_contents($pathToJSONFile, $json, FILE_APPEND);
```

I also wrote a webpage to present the log in a table. with the entries from the form and also presents the json record so it can easily be moved from the log into another json file if accepted as valid update.

the relevant code to read the json is below. The log gile is read, converted to an array by the EOL record separater. The $log associative array is indexed by the json string and points to an associative array with the contents of each record.

```
$json = file_get_contents($logFile);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $json);
$log = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  $log[$line] = json_decode($line,true);
}
```

An html table is created inside a loop

```
foreach ($log as $field => $entry) 
          ...
    $field = addslashes($field);
    echo "<td><a HREF=\"javascript:PopUP('$field')\">JSON</a></td>";
}
```

The PopUP script is very simple it displays the string passed to it in an alert box

```
function PopUP($str) {alert($str);})
```

the trouble I am running into is that the PopUP is not working because the json string is not being passed correctly.

```
<tr id=RV1 class=Royal> 
    <td style='text-align:right'> <a href="#RoyalVillas"> Royal </a> </td> 
    <td> <a HREF="javascript:PopUP('Link not yet available!\nCheck back soon.')"> RV1 </a> </td> 
    <td>  </td><td>  </td> <td style='text-align:left'> <details> <summary> 3 </summary>Street:1 MBR,0 BR <br> Upper:0 MBR,2 BR <br> Lower: MBR, BR <br> </details></td> 
    <td style='text-align:left'> Very nice. Highly recommended. Upstairs Theatre Seating </td>
    <td><a HREF="javascript:PopUP('{\"Sect\":\"Royal\",\"Villa#\":\"1\",\"VillaName\":\"\",\"Owner\":\"\",\"OwnerSite\":\"\",\"BRs\":\"3\",\"StreetMBR\":\"1\",\"StreetBR\":\"0\",\"UpperMBR\":\"0\",\"UpperBR\":\"2\",\"LowerMBR\":\"\",\"LowerBR\":\"\",\"Comments\":\"Very nice. Highly recommended. Upstairs Theatre Seating\"}')">JSON</a></td></tr>
```

the last  is what is not working right - the one in the 2nd  does work right

I tried removing the addslashes function which changed the last entry to

```
<td><a HREF="javascript:PopUP('{"Sect":"Royal","Villa#":"1","VillaName":"","Owner":"","OwnerSite":"","BRs":"3","StreetMBR":"1","StreetBR":"0","UpperMBR":"0","UpperBR":"2","LowerMBR":"","LowerBR":"","Comments":"Very nice. Highly recommended. Upstairs Theatre Seating"}')">JSON</a></td>
```

which looks prettier but has the same symptom. I believe it is because of the quotes which is why I did the addslashes in the first place.

sorry for the long entry but I hope I can get some suggestions on how to accomplish what I intend.

Comment: I would try this first: From PHP pass the JSON by first encoding it with json_encode function and on the JS side you should do JSON.parse of that passed string. Those two functions have their native ways of handling quotes and stuff so it should (in theory) take care of everything.

Comment: There's no quote escaping in HTML attributes. You should find a way to do this in a script rather than inline attributes.

Comment: _"the link seems to be truncated"_ - well, of course. `<a HREF="javascript:PopUP('{"Date":` - you used a double quote as the starting delimiter of the attribute value here, so the _next_ double quote, is taken as the ending delimiter. As already said, "masking" via backslash doesn't work here - the context in not JavaScript, it is HTML. You can use `htmlspecialchars` on the JSON string you are inserting there, to convert all double quotes it contains into the HTML entity `&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

duh -- interesting how your mind convinces itself that your eyes see what you intend instead of what you did.

I changed my php to

```
$field=htmlspecialchars($field);
echo "<br><a HREF=\"javascript:PopUP('$field')\">JSON</a>";
```

and all is well now

thanks to all that commented...